# How to include libgit2 via cmake

Tags: cmake, libgit2

How can i include libgit2 as a library in cmake.
I have cloned the libgit2 repository from github.
than I ran

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Than I found the installed files under /usr/local/include/git2/ and /usr/local/include.

what do I have to put in my cmake file now?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I would build libgit2 as part of your project like this:

```
# Set libgit2 options (e.g. disable shared lib)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
...

# Build libgit2
add_subdirectory(path/to/libgit2)

# Add your own exe or library target
add_executable(my_exe ...)

# Link libgit2 into your exe or library
target_link_libraries(my_exe git2 ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `add_**sub**directory()` function has to be relative to the project path hence the name, any suggestions on how to get around this, or was your suggestion to copy the `libgit2.so` file into the src directory?

Comment: No, my suggestion really is to copy the libgit2 source it into your project as a subdirectory. In my case it's also a git submodule. You may want to look at the cmake ExternalProject module to build outside of the source tree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jason I'm not really doing an out of src build _per se_. [tag:Clion] builds the src and I've just made it output the executable into a sub folder with the source. I'm somewhat confused generally with cmake, there is the approach @x64architecture mentions in his answer, which has a `findxxx.cmake` and then there is also the `find_package` method which uses pkg-config. The pkg-config _way works for me with gtk+3 but not with libgit2 [and yes `pkg-config` knows where libgit2 is on my system]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example tailor it to your own project:

add the following to your top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(git2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GIT2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(lg2 main.c) # can be add_library, etc.

target_link_libraries(lg2 ${GIT2_LIBRARIES})
```

Create a directory called cmake then create a file in it called Findgit2.cmake and add the following to it:

```
# Find git2 Library
#
#  GIT2_INCLUDE_DIRS - where to find git2.h, etc.
#  GIT2_LIBRARIES    - List of libraries when using libgit2.
#  GIT2_FOUND        - True if libgit2 is found.

# GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH
find_path(GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH NAMES git2.h)
# GIT2_LIBRARY
find_library(GIT2_LIBRARY NAMES git2)

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set GIT2_FOUND to TRUE if
# all listed variables are TRUE
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(libgit2 REQUIRED_VARS GIT2_LIBRARY GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH)


if (GIT2_FOUND)
  set(GIT2_INCLUDE_DIR  ${GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH})
  set(GIT2_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH})
  set(GIT2_LIBRARIES    ${GIT2_LIBRARY})
endif()

mark_as_advanced(
  GIT2_INCLUDE_PATH
  GIT2_LIBRARY
)
```

Comment: ok so with [tag:clion] it validates the `CMakeLists.txt` fine, but upon compile it gives me undefined references in my code :/ like this _main.c:9: undefined reference to `giterr_last'_ [trying to build general.c from the examples.] **Any ideas.. ?**